# Inno Setup Text on wpSelectComponents

Tags: inno-setup

Attempting to place some text on wpSelectComponents form.

I can display a button on this WizardForm and I can display a panel (by declaring surface as WizardForm and `visible=False` until `CurrPageId = wpSelectComponents`) but I cannot seem to display a text message.

I can display text inside of the panel (as a caption) but I cannot use `chr(13)` to create a newline.

Is it possible to display text on a predefined wizard page? (two short paragraphs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to show a panel with a button and a label with more than one line of text, only under the content of a certain page (in this case the *Select Components* page), you might take inspiration in the following script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Components]
Name: "main"; Description: "Main Files"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "help"; Description: "Help Files"; Types: full
Name: "help\english"; Description: "English"; Types: full
Name: "help\dutch"; Description: "Dutch"; Types: full

[Code]
var
  Panel: TPanel;

procedure FuncButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MsgBox('You did it!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var  
  DescLabel: TLabel;
  FuncButton: TNewButton;
  ContentHeight: Integer;
begin
  ContentHeight := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Top + 
    WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height;

  Panel := TPanel.Create(WizardForm);
  Panel.Parent := WizardForm;
  Panel.Left := 4;
  Panel.Top := ContentHeight + 4;
  Panel.Width := WizardForm.BackButton.Left - 8;
  Panel.Height := WizardForm.ClientHeight - ContentHeight - 8;
  Panel.Visible := False;

  FuncButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  FuncButton.Parent := Panel;
  FuncButton.Left := (Panel.Height - FuncButton.Height) div 2;
  FuncButton.Top := (Panel.Height - FuncButton.Height) div 2;
  FuncButton.Caption := 'Click me!';
  FuncButton.OnClick := @FuncButtonClick; 

  DescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  DescLabel.Parent := Panel;
  DescLabel.AutoSize := True;
  DescLabel.Caption := 'Hello,' #13#10 + 'I''m your label! :-)';
  DescLabel.Left := FuncButton.Left + FuncButton.Width + 8;
  DescLabel.Top := (Panel.Height - DescLabel.Height) div 2;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  Panel.Visible := CurPageID = wpSelectComponents;
end;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Once again you have guided me in my understanding how to do things in Inno Setup.  I do have one question in regards to the help specifically the Support Classes Reference.  After following your excellent example and integrating it into my setup I decided to add a border to the DescLabel.  When you check the help everything is prefaced with a T such as TBorderWidth, but if you attempt to use it you get an error but if you remove the T it works.  There must be a reason for the T but I can't see what it is. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: That `T` stands for type just like `TLama` is type of `Lama` and it's just an unwritten standard. What you've attempted to change was the `BorderWidth` property which is of type `TBorderWidth`. But your request to have a border around the label is not that easy, since `TLabel` nor `TNewStaticText` (similar to label component) doesn't have a border support. I would personally use yet another panel and put that label on it.

Comment: To find out, which properties are available for a certain class type, e.g. for that `TLabel`, you'll need to go through the inheritance tree of that class. For instance `TLabel` is defined as `TLabel = class(TCustomLabel)` which means it is inherited from `TCustomLabel` class; `TCustomLabel` is defined as `TCustomLabel = class(TGraphicControl)`, so it is inherited from `TGraphicControl` and so forth (you can click the class ancestors for simple navigation in help). And each class in this class tree can add its published properties, whose you can use in your script.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the [DescriptiveTypes script](http://www.mirality.co.nz/inno.php); it juggles some controls on this page to show a detailed description of the currently selected Type.  With a border.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to play around with this. When I was references border width what I meant was Panel.  I was able to do what I wanted with the TBorderStyle = bsraised.  One of the problems I have is finding (and understanding) some of the more useful scripts so I basically copy, paste, see what it does and then try changing things until I get what I like.  However this can have unintended results. The Inno Setup Dialog Files on the same page seem to be an interesting concept.